# How to use ' and " when using HTML and Python together

Tags: javascript, python

I am using Javascript, Python and HTML to make a web app. The problem I am facing is this:

```
print("<p id='" + arr14.index(eachP) + "'>" + eachP + "</p>" + "<br />")
```

I am trying to assign each paragraph a different id using normal HTML and Python syntax (btw it's a .py file) but I can't. I know it's the issue with my `'` and `"` but, I really can't figure it out.

This is usually my only blunder as I couldn't figure it out how the quotes(`'` and `"`)  work in HTML with variables from programming languages like Python or Javascript etc.

Please guide me how this thing actually works as this is the second time I am stuck with this problem.

Comment: BTW arr14 is an array I used in Python and eachP is each element in the array. This line of code above is used inside a for loop in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just switch the `'` and `"` to achieve your goal:

```
print('<p id="' + arr14.index(eachP) + '">' + eachP + '</p>' + '<br />')
```

However, a more readable way for you would be this:

```
print('<p id="{}">{}</p><br />'.format(arr14.index(eachP), eachP)
```

Comment: WOW, thanks a lot. I tried the second option as you suggested and it's working fine. Thanks again ^.^